# Trying to remove row(s) from listview

Tags: c#, listview

My code correctly identifies listview rows based on a textbox search criteria. However when I try to remove the unwanted row(s) I get an error message:-

InvalidArgument=Value of '-1' is not valid for 'index'.

I would be very grateful if someone could help me resolve this issue.. Thanks in advance.

```
  foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items){
      foreach (ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem subItem in item.SubItems){
          if (subItem.Text.ToLower().StartsWith(textBox1.Text.ToLower())){
               var index = item.Index;
               int.TryParse(listView1.Items[index].SubItems[4].Text, out val);
               store[pos] = val;
               pos++;
               count++;
          }else{
               listView1.Items[index].Remove();
          }
      }
  }
```

Comment: What line of code throws that exception? Do you have any **other** variables in that class / function with the name of `index`?

Comment: Thanks for your early response...  this is the line giving me the problem and no, there is no other variables with the name index....................        listView1.Items[index].Remove();

Comment: Sorry... I might of misled you, the code does compile. This error is a runtime error

Comment: Sorry please ignore the previous comment ... I might of misled you, this is the error message and I even changed the variable name:-- CS0103 The name 'index' does not exist in the current context

Comment: InvalidArgument=Value of '-1' is not valid for 'index'.. ... this message was a runtime message.. Now when I right-click on index, a messagebox come up with cannot navigate to the symbol under the carnet.

Comment: I have been trying different option to resolve this problem. First I had listView1.Items[item.Index].Remove(); This compiled but generated this error:- InvalidArgument=Value of '-1' is not valid for 'index' ..... so I tried listView1.Items[index].Remove();

Comment: It is **critical** that the code in your question actually compiles.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you do not calculate your index in clause 'else'

```
}else{
           listView1.Items[index].Remove();
      }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response... is it possible for you to expand on your comment or elaborate more...

Comment: Your comment sounds very interesting... is it possible you could elaborate some more or show me how to resolve it?  Thanks

Comment: @BOB.G, your index wasn't initialized anywhere. for example, if your first step of cycle is going to the 'else' construction, compiler has not initialized index.

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove items from a collection you are iterating through Foreach, c# will throw an error because the collection changed, use for instead, and do it from the end to beginning (so you won't jump items when removing)

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

Comments are in the code. Feel free to ask if you need additional explanation.

**solution w/ Linq**

```
using System.Linq;
...

//cast ListViewItemCollection as List<ListViewItem> for easier manipulation
var items = listView1.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>();
//first, get all items that don't have text matching with textBox text
List<int> itemIndexes = 
    items
        .Where(item => !item.Text.ToLower().StartsWith(textBox1.Text.ToLower()))
        .Select(item => item.Index).ToList();
int val;
//now, with all those indexes do your stuff
itemIndexes.ForEach(index =>
    {
        int.TryParse(listView1.Items[index].SubItems[4].Text, out val);
        store[pos] = val;
        pos++;
        count++;
    });

//lastly, sort indexes descending (for example: 10, 5,4,1) and remove them from listview
itemIndexes
    .OrderByDescending(i=>i)
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(index => listView1.Items.RemoveAt(index));
```

EDIT: chaged code that it removes items that *don't* start with text box' text (like OP wanted).

EDIT 2: since you don't want to use Linq, you can solve your problem using plain old lists and loops

Main thing is, as I said in a comment, not to remove items inside of foreach loop but after you found all items that need to be removed.
Code is tested and working (without 4 lines with missing variables `store`, `val` etc ...)

**solution w/o Linq**

```
//list to hold intem indexes
List<int> itemIndexes = new List<int>(); 

foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
{
    foreach (ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem subItem in item.SubItems)
    {
        var index = item.Index;
        if (subItem.Text.ToLower().StartsWith(textBox1.Text.ToLower()))
        {
            //your code (which doesnt compile since you didn't paste whole code)
            //to test this, I had to remove following 4 lines.
            int.TryParse(listView1.Items[index].SubItems[4].Text, out val);
            store[pos] = val;
            pos++;
            count++;
        }
        else
        {
            itemIndexes.Add(index);
        }
    }
}
//lastly, sort indexes descending (for example: 10, 5,4,1)
//because if you remove item 1, whole list will shorten and 
//you'll get index out of bounds error (in last step when 
//trying to remove item with 10 but last index is 7)...
itemIndexes.Reverse();
//... and remove them from listview
foreach (int index in itemIndexes)
{
    listView1.Items.RemoveAt(index);
}
```

**tested with sample data** - code will remove items that don't start with `a`, like `bbb` and `dd`)

```
ListView listView1 = new ListView();
listView1.Items.Add("aaa");
listView1.Items.Add("bbb");
listView1.Items.Add("ax");
listView1.Items.Add("dd");
TextBox textBox1 = new TextBox();
textBox1.Text = "a";
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your early response. I must admit, I am not fan of nor have never used System.Linq before. Nevertheless, I will put this on the back burner pending other results. I hope you don't mind. Thanks again!

Comment: @BOB.G LOL :) It would be good to start using Linq. After all, under the hood it's just good old iteration. Anyhow, main thing in your code is not to remove items inside of foreach loop; you can't do that because removing changes collection and you'll get an exception. Add indexes to some list and remove them later, like I didn in last step. If there's noone with solution that you're more fond of, I'll write you foreach version. :) Cheers

Comment: That makes sense! is it possible you could help me to write/code this method? I will now start dismantling the else section..